# Truncate a post according to a separator

Tags: twig

Is there a Twig filter that truncates a string according to a separator, like:

```
Lorem to be included ....
# separator #
Lorem to be excluded ..
```

I've found the truncate filter, but it may break the HTML code as it may exclude closing tags and this approach is random, it doesn't give control on the breakpoint that may serve as a preview.

Comment: Did you look at [split](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html)?

Comment: Thank's, I think that it's what I am looking for.